# Working with methods in Java

Tags: java

I've created 2 methods in Java declared public int where each of them returns a value.  I want to create another public int method which returns a value that is sum of these the values of 2 first methods. When I execute the value isn't correct. Can someone help me with creating this method which returns the sum of the other method's values. Here are my methods just for example.

```html
    public int a() {
        int nr=7;
int c=4;
sum=nr+c;
        return sum;
    }

    public int b() {
       
         int l=7;
int m=4;
sum=m+l;
        return sum;
      
    }

    public int c() {
        int sum = 0;
        sum = a() + b();
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the contents of `numrat`, the expected output and the actual output. _"the value isn't correct"_ is not sufficient information for anybody to help you.

Comment: Have you confirmed that a() and b() are in fact producing the correct results?  If not, then there is no way to verify that a() + b() is correct.

Comment: Yes the a() and b() are producing the correct result

Comment: Please give us the output vs the expected output

Comment: what is produced by c?

Comment: Hey my code is very complicated.I just brought this plain example for you!

Comment: Is this the correct way of summing the return values of some methods?

Comment: yes, it is correct way of summing values returned by methods

Comment: You should try to install and IDE (like eclipse ecc.) it will help to find what is wrong, I give you this suggestion since asking simple debugging question on SO will final lead to question ban due to down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you program has many error which are corrected as follows:

```
public class Af {

    public Af() {
    }

    int sum1 = 0;

    public int a() {
        int nr = 7;
        int c = 4;
        sum1 = nr + c;
        return sum1;
    }

    public int b() {

        int l = 7;
        int m = 4;
        int sum2 = m + l;
        return sum2;

    }

    public int c() {
        int sum3 = 0;
        sum3 = a() + b();
        return sum3;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this question probably will be close, however you should consider to format your answer...